# Access the 'More...' View Controller of UITabBarController in SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, swift3

Is there a way to access the 'More...' part of UITabBarController? Since my UITabBarController is not the root, it's being opened by a cell from a navigation-tableview controller, several problems occur (like I cannot see the navigation bar of UIViews attached to UITabBarController, so what I did was to pro grammatically add UIBarButtontems in each UIView controllers. Yet because of this, it 'overwrites' the Edit portion of the 'More...' that enables repositioning of tabs. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: do you have enough rep to add image(s) that explain this problem better?

Answer (score 0):

You can try from here `moreNavigationController`... Or you can try to explain better.